# configuration Thread PHP not work

Tags: php, pthreads

I have a problem with threads php. I copied files (pthreadVC2.dll in "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3" and php_pthreads.dll in "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext") and I added this line (extension=php_pthreads.dll) in php.ini

This is my code:

```
class Thread1 extends Thread{
public function process($pParams=null){
    sleep ($pParams->time);
    return "Fin après".$pParams->time ."secondes";
}
}

    $manager = _class("thread|threadmanager");
    $manager->add("monmodule|thread1",_ppo(array('time'=>2)));
    $manager->add("monmodule|thread1",_ppo(array('time'=>3)));
    $manager->add("monmodule|thread1",_ppo(array('time'=>1)));
    $reponses = $manager->execute();
```

But I have always this problem:

> (Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in..)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the extension is really loaded via `phpinfo()`?

Comment: create a new file and call `phpinfo();`, then check it in the browser, there should be somewhere a hint that Thread extension is loaded

Comment: Thread safety is simething else but you need it enabled to use pthreads under windows, so at least this part is correct. Other things I found: 1. WAMP has several php.ini files, so maybe you edited the wrong one 2. pthreads under windows: did you use pthreads-win32?

Comment: thank you but can you explain me how to install pthreads-win32? i downloaded it but i dont know how to install it